# Canonical Transformation "Indirect Approach"

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, poisson-brackets

The Wikipedia article on Canonical Transformations, in the section "[Indirect Approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Indirect_approach)," makes the following argument:

$$ \dot{Q}_{m} = \frac{\partial Q_{m}}{\partial \mathbf{q}} \cdot \dot{\mathbf{q}} + \frac{\partial Q_{m}}{\partial \mathbf{p}} \cdot \dot{\mathbf{p}}$$

$$= \frac{\partial Q_{m}}{\partial \mathbf{q}} \cdot \frac{\partial H}{\partial \mathbf{p}} - \frac{\partial Q_{m}}{\partial \mathbf{p}} \cdot \frac{\partial H}{\partial \mathbf{q}} $$

$$= \lbrace Q_m , H \rbrace $$

And
$$ \frac{\partial H}{\partial P_{m}} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial \mathbf{q}} \cdot \frac{\partial \mathbf{q}}{\partial P_{m}} + \frac{\partial H}{\partial \mathbf{p}} \cdot \frac{\partial \mathbf{p}}{\partial P_{m}} $$

If the transformations are canonical, we can equate the two, leading to the conditions:
$$\left( \frac{\partial Q_{m}}{\partial p_{n}}\right)_{\mathbf{q}, \mathbf{p}} = -\left( \frac{\partial q_{n}}{\partial P_{m}}\right)_{\mathbf{Q}, \mathbf{P}} $$

$$ \left( \frac{\partial Q_{m}}{\partial q_{n}}\right)_{\mathbf{q}, \mathbf{p}} = \left( \frac{\partial p_{n}}{\partial P_{m}}\right)_{\mathbf{Q}, \mathbf{P}} $$

And the analogous argument for momentum leads to the other two equations:
$$ \left( \frac{\partial P_{m}}{\partial p_{n}}\right)_{\mathbf{q}, \mathbf{p}} = \left( \frac{\partial q_{n}}{\partial Q_{m}}\right)_{\mathbf{Q}, \mathbf{P}} $$

$$ \left( \frac{\partial P_{m}}{\partial q_{n}}\right)_{\mathbf{q}, \mathbf{p}} = -\left( \frac{\partial p_{n}}{\partial Q_{m}}\right)_{\mathbf{Q}, \mathbf{P}} $$

How does equating these two equations lead to those conditions? If I equate the two:
$$ \frac{\partial Q_{m}}{\partial \mathbf{q}} \cdot \frac{\partial H}{\partial \mathbf{p}} - \frac{\partial Q_{m}}{\partial \mathbf{p}} \cdot \frac{\partial H}{\partial \mathbf{q}} =\frac{\partial H}{\partial \mathbf{q}} \cdot \frac{\partial \mathbf{q}}{\partial P_{m}} + \frac{\partial H}{\partial \mathbf{p}} \cdot \frac{\partial \mathbf{p}}{\partial P_{m}} $$

$$\frac{\partial H}{\partial \mathbf{p}} \cdot \left(\frac{\partial Q_{m}}{\partial \mathbf{q}} -\frac{\partial \mathbf{p}}{\partial P_{m}} \right) - \frac{\partial H}{\partial \mathbf{q}} \cdot \left(\frac{\partial Q_{m}}{\partial \mathbf{p}} +\frac{\partial \mathbf{q}}{\partial P_{m}} \right)  =0 $$

The temptation is there, of course, to say that the terms in the parentheses are zero, but how can this be justified?

Comment: Because the identities must be true for **every choice** of the Hamiltonian function...

Comment: @ValterMoretti Ah I see. Suppose we had a particular hamiltonian, and we do a change of coordinates, and hamiltonian's equations still remains valid. This does not necessarily mean the transformation was canonical?

Comment: It depends on the definition of canonical transformation you adopt. Canonical transformations preserve the Hamiltonian form of the equations, but the converse it is not valid with the standard definition